# How to create more outputs?

Tags: mining-pools, transaction-data, monero-forks

I forked aeon/monero for fun and to learn. I have seed nodes running, pools running, miners running. The blockchain syncs, nodes connect to eachother. I can send transactions from the cli wallet only using mixin 1.

The only problem I have now is with Nodejs-pool and miner payments. I have set the pool db to mixin 1, the coins config mixin is 1.

From the start the pool does not make payments.
How do I create more outputs?

Anyone know what might be wrong or how to get more outputs some how?

I tried sweep_unmixable but that didnt work.

https://github.com/MoneroOcean/nodejs-pool/issues/36

I can send coins from my wallet cli using mixin 1 but nothing else?

It doesn't work from the pool if I enter mixin 1 in the pool db still not enough outputs for tx.

2018-06-18 13:58:45.853 [RPC0] ERROR wallet.wallet2 src/wallet/wallet2.cpp:6315 !scanty_outs.empty(). THROW EXCEPTION: error::not_enough_outs_to_mix

2018-06-18 13:58:45.868 [RPC0] WARN net.http src/wallet/wallet_errors.h:794 /home/pooldaemon/durinscoin/src/wallet/wallet2.cpp:6315:N5tools5error22not_enough_outs_to_mixE: not enough outputs to use, ring size = 2, scanty_outs:

9.000000000000 - 1

0.800000000000 - 1

0.600000000000 - 1

70.000000000000 - 1

0.020000000000 - 1

Payments module error

payments > 2018-06-19 13:00 +00:00: Issue making payments{"code":-19,"message":"not enough outputs to use Please use sweep_dust."}

payments > Will not make more payments until the payment daemon is restarted!

Some go out if I 0 the balances of miners and they get small payments.

I tried moving coins around and that didnt help.

https://www.reddit.com/r/MoneroMining/comments/8s9fym/how_to_create_more_outputs/

Can anyone explain how outputs are created?

Answer (score 0):

Outputs are only ever created as part of transactions. There are two types of transaction:

1. Coinbase transactions, a special type of transaction created with every block that is mined, which rewards the miner according to the emission schedule and any transaction fees paid.
2. Regular transactions, which spend existing outputs and create new ones.

So just keep mining more blocks and more outputs will be created.

Comment: Hello thank you for the reply, the pool has hundreds of blocks now, payments always have this error. Even when I reset the pool and still as the miners payable balance increase so does the need for more outputs? So with the pool blocks I should not have to worry about outputs? I am still trying to learn how it works but I am not sure why smaller amounts of coins work but the larger payments dont. Should I mine to the wallet before starting the pool to get some I put ready? What about when new people join, they should just be able  to start a pool and not have to worry about getting coins first

Comment: I don't know what's wrong, but I'd guess that perhaps the wallet used by the pool isn't fully synced with your blockchain, meaning that the wallet can't see all of the blocks you've mined yet and therefore can't see enough outputs to use in transactions.

Comment: I can see that the blocks are received by the wallet in the RPC log. Small transactions seem to work but once the miners balance goes over the block size then this error seems to occur. I am not sure how to get around it.

Comment: I think you're having the problem mentioned here: https://github.com/aeonix/aeon/issues/24 Btw your fork will wait until block 1220517 until it will activate RingCT. RingCT does not have the problem of finding outputs of matching sizes to mix with, so moving directly to RingCT now would probably fix this problem. You'll want to change the activation heights here so that you're immediately on version 5 instead of on version 1 https://github.com/monero-project/monero/blob/68e6678ab77f6ba731a8517eb3941b4e554acfc5/src/cryptonote_core/blockchain.cpp#L89